# Is it possible to replace a selector from imported stylesheet?

Tags: css, sass

I want to use these [Pygments stylesheets](https://github.com/richleland/pygments-css) in my site however the selector that they use (`.codehilite`)  does not match the HTML of my site generator which produces code blocks with a `.highlight` class.

I am using SASS and Gulp to process my styles I want to be able to import the style like so:

```
@import "./pygments-css/monokai";
```

Is there a way I can somehow replace the selectors in the imported file?

### Example

```
.codehilite .s { color: #e6db74 }
```

Would need to become this

```
.highlight .s { color: #e6db74 }
```

I was looking at SASS functions such as `selector-replace` but I can't figure out if it would applicable.

Comment: Which site generator are you using?

Comment: I'm using Hugo.

Comment: Are you loading pygments css files form the web? Guess no, so simply go in the files and swap `codehilite` with `highlight`.

Comment: Yes, I have the pygments-css repository as a submodule in my Git repo. What you're suggesting is a simple solution but I would prefer a solution that doesn't require copying or otherwise changing the pygments-css code.

Comment: As per the author of the repo that you are using: * You should change the .codehilite to work with the style name that you use for your Pygments HTML output. * So I guess you can change them :)

Comment: I could... But what fun would that be? ;-) I'm curious if this is possible for other situations as well.

Answer (score 1):

`selector-replace` can be used to achieve what you want but in order for the function to work, you need to call it from the `.codehilite .s` selector otherwise it won't get *overridden*

Below is a code snippet of how you can use it

```
.codehilite .s
  @at-root #{selector-replace(&, '.codehilite', '.highlight')}
    color: #e6db74
```

Which would compile to

```
.highlight .s {
  color: #e6db74;
}
```

But to be completely honest I don't think it's really applicable in your situation because it seems more like overkill when you could just change the `codehilite` selector since none of your HTML elements will use that class. However that decision is up to you. I think you can find a more appropriate use of `selector-replace` [here](https://www.phase2technology.com/blog/everything-you-need-to-know-about-sass-3-4/)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

According to http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-7 there's `@extend`, which works like this:

```
.highlight .s {
    @extend .codehilite .s;
}
```

This should basically take the rules that apply to `.codehilite .s` and apply the same to `.highlight .s`, resulting in:

```
.highlight .s, .codehilite .s {
    color: #e6db74
}
```

**Note:** for this to work Sass needs the original CSS/Sass imported.

Comment: Wouldn't this require me to write that for every rule? Also I think it would give me duplicates in my final CSS file.

Comment: Pygments offers only CSS, no Sass. Your generator only outputs hardcoded classes. Long story short: you either rewrite the Pygments CSS (which means you cannot update anymore later on) or you create a mapping for all rules as showed above. Alternatively write a search-replace program yourself and use it to transform the Pyglets CSS.